# Python function is executed more than once

Tags: python, mysql

I want to get and print all the records from a table in a Mysql DB that is in a VPS but when I use a for loop to print all the records retrieved I get them printed 2-3 times and not just 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Modules imported

# VPS
# Parameters to connecto to de DB in the VPS

def connDB():
    global conn
    global cur
    try:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(DBhost, DBuser, DBpass, DBdb, charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        print("...DB VPS connect")
    except:
        print("...DB VPS ERROR")
        pass

def selectallDB(query):
        global conn
        global cur

        try:
                cur.execute(query)
                localrpis = cur.fetchall()
                conn.commit()
                print("... select All OK")
                print('Total Row(s):', cur.rowcount)
                for i in localrpis:
                        print(i)

        except:
                print("... select ERROR")
                connDBLocal()
                pass

def getallDB():

        c_select = """
        SELECT * FROM %s
        """%(trpistmsMCSIR)
        selectallDB(c_select)


def checktime(sec):
        # Function to trigger the read data funtion from "sec" to "sec"
        while True:
                res = round(time()%sec)
                if res==0.0:
                        getallDB()
                sleep(0.2)  # Changed to 0.5

connDB()

while True:
        checktime(10)
```

I assume that the `for` loop inside the `try` is executed 2 times (sometimes even 3) but I don't get why.

```
...DB connect
...DB VPS connect
... select All OK
('Total Row(s):', 2L)
('SELECT result OK')
... select All OK
('Total Row(s):', 2L)
('SELECT result OK')
```

As a work around after many changes I got it "working" changing the sleep(0.2) to sleep(0.5) but I'm not sure if this resolves the problem or it's just an illusion that the loop is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the `for` loop as can be seen from duplicate `... select All OK` lines. The problem is your `while` loop as `round(0.2)` is equal to `0.0`. That's why it is fixed when you make it `0.5`. Theoretically it may also run 3 times (at seconds 0.0, 0.2, and 0.4) if the database operation is fast enough.

If you want to run your code every 10 seconds, `sleep`ing `0.5` seconds in between checks is a good compromise.

Comment: y `getallDB();sleep(sec) ` is not enough; or
y `getallDB();sleep(sec-db_run_time) ` is not enough;

Comment: @SmartManoj How do you determine the exact `db_run_time`? And what would this earn you?

Comment: some aproximation

Comment: @SmartManoj That won't work as expected, you may never hit `res==0.0` condition if your approximation is off by more than 0.5 seconds.